# iOS how to get rid of extra view padding?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UINavigationController which has a ViewController and it's view has a background image. When I set these constraints on the view I expect it to extend to the edges but it seems to be going to the left and right view layout guides. This leaves me with extra padding that I don't want. Note I not using storyboards and I have set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` incase you think that might be causing an issue. Any help with this issue would be appreciated.

```
    view.addSubview(backgroundImage)

    backgroundImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    backgroundImage.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    backgroundImage.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    backgroundImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: What is the size of your image and what content mode have you set?  AspectFit?  AspectFill?

Comment: thanks yeah that definitely did help me figure it out. I had AspectFit, but of course the aspect ratio was wrong because the top bar was squishing it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that you have set the correct `contentMode` on your `UIImageView`; `.scaleAspectFill` will ensure that the whole image view is filled, but you may lose some of the image due to the clipping required to maintain the correct aspect ratio.